Gpio chips via the linux kernel
I recently used the Linux kernel to control the gpio pins of my raspberry pi 5. In doing so, I noticed that I didn’t need to specify the specific gpio chip that I wanted to initiate. Due to the new gpio controlling chip system that came with the Raspberry Pi 5, I thought that  I needed to first talk to a gpio chip with specific pins allocated to it to control a gpio pin. But I didn’t even have to mention the chip in the kernel, and it still controlled the gpio. I wonder if my perception of gpio chips and the new gpio updates is incorrect, or if there is some other reason why I didn’t need to specify the chip, but I would really appreciate someone explaining this to me. Here are the commands I used to communicate via the kernel:
cd /sys/class/gpio 
echo 512 > export 
cd gpio521 
echo out > direction 
echo 1 > value 

Thanks!!

@Milliways Sorry about my unclear question. Here is what I did:
cd /sys/class/gpio
echo 512 > export
cd gpio521
echo out > direction
echo 1 > value


@Milliways And regarding the "new updates with the gpio" I was told that the pi-5 had been updated with a new chip to previous models, resulting in a new chip-based control system.

@Milliways yes, sorry about the confusion. I’ve updated the original post. Let me know if you need more information .

You are partially correct. Nothing to do with Pi5 but there was a change with kernel 6.6.

"For years now, fixing the base GPIO number to zero has been frowned upon by the kernel devs. In the next kernels we release (6.6) there will be an error message at boot up about it. At the same time, the sysfs interface to the GPIOs has been deprecated - some distributions have already disabled it and are expecting users to go through libgpiod.
The launch of Pi 5 gave us the opportunity to nudge people to update their apps in preparation for the upcoming changes without breaking existing systems. When we launch 6.6 the older Pis will have the same, high-numbered GPIOsn - probably still available by sysfs, but eventually that will be switched off."

It is still deprecated, and I thought the GPIO sysfs had been removed (the old code no longer works) but its use is still inadvisable.
For reference
Pi5 ~ 
$ ls /sys/class/gpio  
export  gpiochip512@  gpiochip544@  gpiochip548@  gpiochip565@  gpiochip571@  unexport  
Pi4 ~ 
$ ls /sys/class/gpio  
export  gpiochip512@  gpiochip570@  unexport  
Pi3+ ~ 
$ ls /sys/class/gpio
export  gpiochip512@  gpiochip566@  unexport

NOTE You HAVE specified the chip (gpiochip512) although the GPIO pins on Pi5 are actually on gpiochip571.
The GPIO numbers start at 512 and are sequential:-
gpiochip0: GPIOs 512-543
gpiochip1: GPIOs 544-547
gpiochip2: GPIOs 548-564
gpiochip3: GPIOs 565-570
gpiochip4: GPIOs 571-624

If you REALLY want to use the command line to manipulate GPIO libgpiod provides user-mode applications to manipulate GPIO lines which should be included in Raspberry Pi OS (at least if you install gpiod).
gpioget – read values of specified GPIO lines
gpioset – set values of specified GPIO lines, potentially keep the lines exported and wait until timeout, user input or signal


Oh I see, just to clarify: the pressure to use gpiod wasn’t really anything to do with the new gpio chip, but due to other changes in the kernel, and the chips don’t actually need to be specified in other libraries but gpio forces you to. Thank you very much for your patience and guidance.

Oh and on more thing: Is there any significance to the gpio being numbered 512, 513 ect instead of 1, 2 and so on in the kernel?

Ahh, I see! Thank you for your assistance.

@Seamus If you install in a venv with pip install gpiod you get the latest. Not quite sure how this works as the old  version of libgpiod seems to be the only version.

Ach - neither do I... AIUI gpiod is a Python library, but is unrelated to libgpiod?! according to this. It doesn't get any crazier than this  :)

@Seamus I had assumed so but have not examined the source. It may use the kernel library (which appears to be up to date). To me much of this is academic as any programs I write use better documented libraries.

Yes, well I'm not a Python user, but this gpiod thing keeps coming up & gets conflated with libgpiod.  I do like to know what a thing is... what a clown show!

@Seamus The method to get the lingpiod tools is to install gpiod using apt. I understand your frustration.
